# How to change max limitation of Text amount in SwiftUI List?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I found an issue by creating a new blank Project, there are only max 10 Text Elements in List, or will cause compile error, can I edit the limitation in anywhere?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("Line 1")
            Text("Line 2")
            Text("Line 3")
            Text("Line 4")
            Text("Line 5")
            Text("Line 6")
            Text("Line 7")
            Text("Line 8")
            Text("Line 9")
            Text("Line 10")

            // Uncomment this line will cause Complie Error
            // Text("Line 11")
        }
    }
}
```

I tried add a model

```
class MyModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var items: [String] = [
        "line 1",
        "line 2",
        "line 3",
        "line 4",
        "line 5",
        "line 6",
        "line 7",
        "line 8",
        "line 9",
        "line 10",
        "line 11",
    ]
}
```

and display list by model data, it is display corrected

```
@ObservedObject var model = MyModel()

var body: some View {

    List {
        ForEach(model.items.indices) { index in
            Text(self.model.items[index])
        }
    }
}
```

So, the problem is not List, is the Function Builder?

Updated a new method, using Group, For VStack, it is OK, But for List, it will display 11 rows, and everyline is overlapped with "Line 11"

```
List {
    Group {
        Text("Line 1")
        Text("Line 2")
        Text("Line 3")
        Text("Line 4")
        Text("Line 5")
        Text("Line 6")
        Text("Line 7")
        Text("Line 8")
        Text("Line 9")
        Text("Line 10")
    }

    Group {
        Text("Line 11")
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to split them up into Groups.

Comment: found an article about this https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/swiftui-tips-and-tricks   said: "All containers in SwiftUI must return no more than ten children, which is usually fine for most purposes. However, if you need to have more than 10 views, if you need to return more than one view from your body property, or if you need to return several different kinds of view, you should use a group like this"

Comment: here has a detail description https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-group-views-together    but if replace VStack to List, text will overlapped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, the problem is not List, is the Function Builder?

Yes, exactly. The problem it's strictly related to how `@ViewBuilder` closures are implemented. At the moment those closures can't take variadic parameters. So, they implement 10 methods this way (you can check these interfaces in xCode):

```
/// Builds an empty view from an block containing no statements, `{ }`.
public static func buildBlock() -> EmptyView

/// Passes a single view written as a child view (e..g, `{ Text("Hello") }`) through
/// unmodified.
public static func buildBlock<Content>(_ content: Content) -> Content where Content : View

public static func buildBlock<C0, C1>(_ c0: C0, _ c1: C1) -> TupleView<(C0, C1)> where C0 : View, C1 : View

public static func buildBlock<C0, C1, C2>(_ c0: C0, _ c1: C1, _ c2: C2) -> TupleView<(C0, C1, C2)> where C0 : View, C1 : View, C2 : View

public static func buildBlock<C0, C1, C2, C3>(_ c0: C0, _ c1: C1, _ c2: C2, _ c3: C3) -> TupleView<(C0, C1, C2, C3)> where C0 : View, C1 : View, C2 : View, C3 : View

public static func buildBlock<C0, C1, C2, C3, C4>(_ c0: C0, _ c1: C1, _ c2: C2, _ c3: C3, _ c4: C4) -> TupleView<(C0, C1, C2, C3, C4)> where C0 : View, C1 : View, C2 : View, C3 : View, C4 : View

public static func buildBlock<C0, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5>(_ c0: C0, _ c1: C1, _ c2: C2, _ c3: C3, _ c4: C4, _ c5: C5) -> TupleView<(C0, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5)> where C0 : View, C1 : View, C2 : View, C3 : View, C4 : View, C5 : View

public static func buildBlock<C0, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6>(_ c0: C0, _ c1: C1, _ c2: C2, _ c3: C3, _ c4: C4, _ c5: C5, _ c6: C6) -> TupleView<(C0, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6)> where C0 : View, C1 : View, C2 : View, C3 : View, C4 : View, C5 : View, C6 : View

public static func buildBlock<C0, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7>(_ c0: C0, _ c1: C1, _ c2: C2, _ c3: C3, _ c4: C4, _ c5: C5, _ c6: C6, _ c7: C7) -> TupleView<(C0, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7)> where C0 : View, C1 : View, C2 : View, C3 : View, C4 : View, C5 : View, C6 : View, C7 : View

public static func buildBlock<C0, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7, C8>(_ c0: C0, _ c1: C1, _ c2: C2, _ c3: C3, _ c4: C4, _ c5: C5, _ c6: C6, _ c7: C7, _ c8: C8) -> TupleView<(C0, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7, C8)> where C0 : View, C1 : View, C2 : View, C3 : View, C4 : View, C5 : View, C6 : View, C7 : View, C8 : View

public static func buildBlock<C0, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7, C8, C9>(_ c0: C0, _ c1: C1, _ c2: C2, _ c3: C3, _ c4: C4, _ c5: C5, _ c6: C6, _ c7: C7, _ c8: C8, _ c9: C9) -> TupleView<(C0, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7, C8, C9)> where C0 : View, C1 : View, C2 : View, C3 : View, C4 : View, C5 : View, C6 : View, C7 : View, C8 : View, C9 : View
```

As you can see the maximum number of parameters a `@ViewBuilder` closure can take is 10.

The solution depends on your needs, if the views inside the closure are basically the same view with different content you should go for a `ForEach` inside a `List` (which are exactly meant for situations like these):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach { val in
                //your view
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If the views are really more than 10 different views you have to rely on the `Group` view splitting views in more than one group:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            Group {
                //10 views
            }

            Group {
                //10 views
            }
        }
    }
}
```